# Not able to call the JS function on the actionlink, used to update the Zone in Tapestry5

Tags: tapestry, actionlink, zone

I am facing one problem in Tapestry.

Problem - I am using a grid to display the data. with each row i am displaying a Plus(+) button. when we click on the Plus(+) button then i'll display the inner rows for that Row. I achieved this statically. Statically means, when Grid load the data at the same time i fetch the data for inner rows and store it into the Hidden fields. when i click on the Plus(+) button then i'll call a JS function which use the Hidden Data field and draw the inner rows.

Now there is a twist. I have to do the same thing dynamically. It means on the click of Plus(+) button i have to fetch the data for hidden rows and then call the JS function to draw the inner rows. To achieve this i have used Zone & ActionLink to get the inner rows data dynamically. Zone contain the Hidden fields which contain the data for the Inner rows. when i click on the ActionLink, Zone get refreshed and fetch the data but after that i am not able to call the JS function.

Hope you guys understood the Problem. Need your help on urgent basis.

Regards,
Mahendra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that you are not able to call the JS function on Zone refresh. so there is one solution.

> A Zone may be initially visible or invisible. When a Zone is updated,
>   it is made visible if not currently so. This is accomplished via a
>   function on the Tapestry.ElementEffect client-side object. By default,
>   the show() function is used for this purpose. If you want Tapestry to
>   call a different Tapestry.ElementEffect function when updates occur,
>   specify its name with the zone's show parameter.
>
> If a Zone is already visible, then a different effect function is used
>   to highlight the change. By default, the highlight() function is
>   called, which performs a yellow fade to highlight that the content of
>   the Zone has changed. Alternatively, you can specify a different
>   effect function with the Zone's update parameter:
>   To have Tapestry update a zone without the usual yellow highlight
>   effect, just specify "show" for the update parameter:

```
<t:zone t:id="myZone" t:update="show">
```

> You may also define and use your own JavaScript effect function (with
>   lower-case names), like this:

```
    Tapestry.ElementEffect.myeffectname = function(element){
 YourJavascriptCodeGoesHere; };
```

So in your case you can use like below code

```
<t:zone t:id="zoneId" t:update="yourfunction" >
// contain the your code                           
</t:zone>
```

so when Zone get refresh it will call yourfunction.

for more info [Zone Effect Functions](http://tapestry.apache.org/ajax-and-zones.html)

Enjoy.

Regards,
Mahendra